# Selenium: Use selenium to login returns 400 (Bad Request) but returns 200 when login manually

Tags: selenium

I am using Selenium, python and Chrome to automate UI login process.

- Selenium:  3.141.0
- Python: 3.7
- Chrome: 86.0.4240.111 (Official Build) (32-bit)

When use selenium to login, it returns 400 (Bad Request). And I have checked login manually it does work correctly.

Firstly I think it should be request header problem. And I changed the request headers almost the same as the manual request. But still does not work. Anyone have any experience on this?

Here is the manual login request snapshots:

[image]

[image]

Here are the request made by selenium.

[image]

[image]

Both requests URL are the same, like: http://abc.org.cn/cd/ef/index.do#/login

Thanks.

Comment: I would check if your login password has any character that needs to be escaped. Try to print the password before Selenium tries to type it in and make sure that it's the correct one.

Comment: You're missing some cookies.

Comment: @laurentiurad, thanks, it's not related to the password.

Comment: @pguardiario, thanks. Maybe you are right, but the cookies are generated automatically, and for Selenium, it just to request the same url.